# Mysterious rounded line appears at top of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, drawing

I have a mysterious problem with a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`. The cell subclass is doing some relatively complex layout of `UIControl` instances, and then storing its height (based on the layout of those controls) in an ivar. I am performing zero custom drawing (I'm not overriding `drawRect:` at all).

For some reason, there is this strange rounded-corner-looking thing drawing at the top of the cell no matter what the height. I'm not changing the height of the cell's frame itself or anything; I'm just using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` in my table view delegate. Everything else about the cell renders fine—it's just this one strange part.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this happen before? I am using iOS 4.2.

[image: image of mysterious arc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to call `[super layoutSubviews]` in your subclass' `layoutSubviews` method even though Apple's API docs say that the default implementation does nothing. Doing this fixed this problem (as well as turning off all autoresizing of subviews).

Comment: The default implementation in `UIView` does nothing. `UITableViewCell` definitely does something.